# Data in Provider Can't Load in initState

Tags: flutter, provider

"When I first install and open the data provider application like MenuProvider, it doesn't load or fetch on the splash screen when I call it in initState, is there anything wrong with the code? Is there any other way besides calling it in initState?"

[For picture of Menu not Show/fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWKnR.jpg)

**This Is My Code**

```html
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      try {
        await getInit();
        await getAndSaveDeviceInformation();
        await printIps();
        await checkLocation();
        await autoLogin();
      } catch (e) {
        // Handle or report error
        print('An error occurred: $e');
      }
    });
  }
```

```html
Future<void> autoLogin() async {
    const FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

    String? accessToken;
    try {
      accessToken = await storage.read(key: 'accessToken');
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      // Handle the exception
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Failed to read access token: $e');
      }
    }

    if (accessToken != null) {
      await Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchMenu(categories: ''); <-- menu Provider unfetchable 
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const MainPage(
            currentIndex: 0,
          ),
        ),
      );
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      await Provider.of<MenuProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .fetchMenu(categories: '');
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const MainPage2(),
        ),
      );
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  Future<void> getInit() async {
    if (mounted) {
      context.read<BannerProvider>().getBanner();
      context.read<CategoryProvider>().fetchCategory();
      // context.read<MenuProvider>().fetchMenu(categories: '');
      context.read<OutletProvider>().fetchOutlet();
      context.read<UpdateAppWarningProvider>().fetchUpdateWarning();

      // context.read<MenuProvider>().fetchMenu(categories: '');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use await inside getInit() for every function that returns a Future.

Comment: I have added await inside getInit() but it still does not appear and MenuProvider is not loaded/fetched